# Create simple webpage (IIS) that accepts a value from hyperlink and offers the value as a file download with whatever extension

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

The page or script or whatever will be hosted on IIS and should basically accept a value from an hyperlink [www.whatever.com?parametervalue=test](http://www.whatever.com?parametervalue=test) and offer a file download with for example the name, myfile.file, containing the value 'test'.

The parametervalue should have not characterlimit in the URL because it's possible that the value that is passed is a very long string with 4000 characters or more.

I am not sure how to go about this. What technology can I use to get this done, html/javascript perhaps? I have tried Google'ing but cannot think of the right combination of words to pinpoint what I am looking for.

How can I get this done?

Comment: Well, perhaps the real question is where does the list of file(s) come from that you want to provide and pass to that URL? That list has to come from some place. Perhaps the data source or origin of the list of files should be passed in place of the actual list of files then? In other words, where does that list come from in the first place? How that list is to be created is perhaps what we pass - and then we generate the list in the target page the same way? Or why not pass the array/list of files to that page in session in place of a long ugly URL set of paramters?

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal it's an XML string that comes from an SSRS report, we want the user to be able to click a hyperlink that activates a download, offering the user to download the XML string to a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so we have some web page. User clicks on some button. That button can then walk the dog, do payroll, and THEN we also want to take some xml file, and pass that to the next page, in which we offer a download button.

So, seems VERY little need to use or have or want or even consider using parameters in the URL here. Besides attempting to pass a xml string in a paramter would and could introduce all kinds of issues and probelms.

So, in first page:

Button click (why some hyper link???? makes zero sense here).

that button click as noted can do whatever we want, inclduing that of gettitng and obatining the xml file, and of couse we want to also provide and include a file name for the download.

so, on that 1st page, dump the use of a hyper link, and use a button.

That button will

Get the xml data we want, and save into sesison

```
 session["XMLData"] = " my messy and ugly xml string/data here";

 session["XMLFileName] = "ssrs.xml";

 Response.Redirect("MyDownloadpage.aspx"); // jump to page with download button
```

Now, on the target page, we have that download button.

That download button can then do this:

```
public void DownLoadFile()
{
string strXMLData = Session["MyXMLData"] as string;
string strFile = Session["MyFile"] as string;
string MineType =  MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(strFile)

Response.Buffer = false; 
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();

Response.AddHeader("Accept-Header", strXMLData.Length.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", strXMLData.Length.ToString());

Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strFile);

Response.AddHeader("Expires", "0");
Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "private");
Response.ContentType = strMineType;
Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
Response.Write(strXMLData);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
}
```

So, from the page that jumps to your page with some information and the download button,, you can use code like above.

To pass the xml data, and the xml file name to be used, you can use session[] as per above.

## Edit: Get the url paramter

As noted in comments, the xml data is to be passed in the URL, so now the above code becomes this:

```
    string strXMLData = Request.QueryString["data"];
```

Of course you replace "data" with whatever the name of the parameter value passed is.

Or, just grab the first value, say like this:

```
    string strXMLData = Request.QueryString[0];  // manybe use 1 - depends on what url looks like
```

Comment: The thing is, we are bound by SSRS and cannot use any buttons. Inside a SSRS report you can use a hyperlink only. I would like to click this hyperlink, which points to the webpage that will automatically offer the user the download of the XML string (the XML string is passed from the SSRS hyperlink to the 'download webpage')

Comment: Then just use   Request.QueryString["parm name here"] - so see my edit. the code will be the same - just that you now use QueryString in place of session - rest of the code should remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question well you want to make link so when someone visits it download a file.
Then you can create download.php file and write there

```
if ($_GET["parametervalue"] == "file1") {
echo "<script>(script to download your file)</script>";
}
```